# How to get two images to overlap without SVG

Tags: html, css, position

I have a logo and a small version of the logo that doesn't have the words. I want to have the two images overlapping so that when the page loads the large version will fade out and the axes will fade in in the same place that they were in the large version. Here is a gif of what I mean

[image]

I'm not sure if there is a special trick to this but everything I've tried, moving one thing moves the other and I can't get them to overlap properly without it screwing up. I want the logo to be in the middle of the area above the red arrow.
[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/lujihizazo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both images in a container who has `position: relative`, and give the images `position: absolute`. This way you'll be able to position the images on top of each other and give them exact `top` and `left` coordinates.

**html**

```
<div id="logo-container">
    <img id="logo1"></img>
    <img id="logo2"></img>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#logo-container {
    position: relative;
}

#logo-container > img {
    position: absolute;
}

#logo1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#logo2 {
    top: 200px; // change me
    left: 130px; // change me
}
```

Comment: in my example I have them in main which is relative and they are both absolute

Comment: `.logo_small` has `margin-top: -450px`, which is why it's not appearing off screen. You should position the images with `left` and `top`

Comment: what is the difference between margin-left and left? @Kable